# Boost::Fibonacci_Heap::top() object destroyed before assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have the following loop in a class method:

```
vector<PuzzleImpl> PuzzleImpl::performMove()
{
    //! Remove a single move from mMoves and store it in aMove.
    MovesImpl aMove = mMoves.top();
    mMoves.pop();

    //! Cached local variables.
    vector<size> soln = aMove.getSoln();
    size RID = aMove.getRowID();
    size CID = aMove.getColID();
    size BID = aMove.getBlockID();
    bool solvable = true;

    //! Return Vector, will store all possible moves from aMove.
    vector<PuzzleImpl> neighbours;

    //! Build all Boards and update Moves Queue for a move from top of mMoves.
    while (!soln.empty()) {
        //! Store local copies to update without being destructive to original.
        // Also reset updatedMoves and updatedBoard for next iteration.
        fib_heap tempHeap = mMoves;
        fib_heap updatedMoves;
        Board<size> updatedBoard = mBoard;

        //! Get a <value>, remove it form <soln>.
        size value = soln.back();
        soln.pop_back();

        //! Update Board with the move.
        updatedBoard.set(RID, CID, value);

        //! Iterate through the mMoves queue and update for the removed move.
        while (!tempHeap.empty()) {
            //! Get an element, remove it from the heap.
            MovesImpl temp = tempHeap.top();
            tempHeap.pop();

            //! If the temp object shares the same RID/CID/BID remove <value>.
            if ((temp.getRowID() == RID) || (temp.getColID() == CID) 
                                                || (temp.getBlockID() == BID)) {
                temp.removeMove(value);
            }

            //! Check if we can solve the puzzle form this position. If you have
            //  a blank position left but there are have no moves from that
            //  position, a solution is unattainable. - HALT.
            if (temp.getSolnSize() == 0) {
                solvable = false;
                break;
            }

            //! Add the Moves object to the updatedMoves Heap.
            updatedMoves.push(temp);
        }

        //! If the puzzle is solvable from this position with the current move,
        //  generate new PuzzleImpl object using the Board and Moves Vec.
        neighbours.push_back(PuzzleImpl(updatedBoard, updatedMoves, solvable));
    }

    //! Return the Vector containing all possible states from this move.
    return neighbours;
}
```

The problem I have is in the line:

```
MovesImpl temp = tempHeap.top();
```

I get an access violation (Access violation reading location 0x0000000C.) stating that <*src*>'s memory can't be read and <*this*> is set to random values in memory. MovesImpl doesn't have any heap allocation, its stack based and I thus use the default assignment operator. I have specified the copy ctor.

Any ideas? Input greatly appreciated.

/Thanks!

Comment: You don't show relevant code. Make it a SSCCE and we'll look at it

Comment: sehe: Thanks for the tip, I am new too this. I've tried making an SSEEC, but its too complex, I'd need to open source the whole project. Since pop returns a reference to the object removed from the heap, could it be that the objects destructor is called before it gets the chance to be assigned? Could that be the issue here, if so any ideas on a work around?

Comment: I can only refer you to these: **[See also Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**. Divide and conquer. Programming is hard :|